# Python : Predict number of tweets from a user

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, regression

I am trying to predict number of tweets a user will make based on historical count of tweets and moving averages. I am a python developer, but total noob in ML. Below are the data sets I have for example from user @POTUS :

```
Date | Number of tweets

01-03-2017 : 3
02-03-2017 : 2
03-03-2017 : 7
06-03-2017 : 2
07-03-2017 : 6
08-03-2017 : 6
09-03-2017 : 5
10-03-2017 : 5
11-03-2017 : 6
13-03-2017 : 11
14-03-2017 : 5
15-03-2017 : 10
16-03-2017 : 6
17-03-2017 : 7
18-03-2017 : 3
19-03-2017 : 2
20-03-2017 : 6
21-03-2017 : 9
22-03-2017 : 1
23-03-2017 : 3
24-03-2017 : 4
```

I also computed the 7 and 3 days moving average using https://github.com/linsomniac/python-movingaverage/blob/master/movingaverage.py

```
Moving Average, 3 days : 
[4.0, 3.67, 5.0, 4.67, 5.67, 5.33, 5.33, 7.33, 7.33, 8.67, 7.0, 7.67, 5.33, 4.0, 3.67, 5.67, 5.33, 4.33, 2.67, 4.0, 3.67, 4.33, 4.33, 6.0, 6.67, 5.67, 3.67, 2.33]

Moving Average, 7 days : 
[4.43, 4.71, 5.29, 5.86, 6.29, 6.86, 6.86, 7.14, 6.86, 6.29, 5.57, 6.14, 4.86, 4.43, 4.0, 4.29, 4.29, 4.29, 3.71, 4.57, 5.29, 5.0, 4.43, 4.71]
```

I understand that this is a regression problem but not quite sure how to take this further. What should be my approach to predict how many tweets the user will make in next few days ?

Comment: This is off-topic and too broad a question for SO. Try researching machine learning algorithms to find ways to approach making predictions.

Comment: and other features than just previous tweet counts... (otherwise you can only to auto-regression)

Answer (score 0):

The data you posted is formatted as:

[date format] [number format]

To perform a numerical regression, the information formatted as a date must be formatted as a number.  This is commonly done by converting the information into days since a particular date.  If you format the data as:

[days since 01-03-2017] [number of tweets]

it would be more amenable to numerical analysis.  I suggest that after reformatting the data, you make a scatter plot and see if there is a visible trend of some kind that might be mathematically modeled.  If you do not see some sort of trend in data this simple, then machine learning will probably not find one either.